# Merging the same data but in two different datasets

Tags: sas

I have to merge these two sets of data, which contains exactly the same data, but written in different ways:

[Offsite data](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/learn-ap-southeast-1-prod-fleet02-xythos/593a61e7aa84f/4347788?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27Assignment%25203%2520Q4.txt&response-content-type=text%2Fplain&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20181112T092342Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=21600&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJDDBGKVKR5QVHNHA%2F20181112%2Fap-southeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=e229ba01805398fa1e367d1334ea986c28cfbba2aab8b17846e89c9f852b5873):

```
* (i);
A123   4Mar1989    8,60000
A037  23Jun1957   21,45000
M015  19Sep1977   17,50000

* (ii);
A123  4Mar1989  8,6,00
***************
    A037 23Jun1957  21,450
**************
 M015 19Sep1977$17,500
***********
```

The first record should have

```
ID = "A123", DEPT = "A", BIRTHDAY = 10655, YEAR = 1989, SALARY = 8600
```

So far my approach has been(which doesn´t work):

```
data i;
   input $ID $Dep $BIRTHDAY $YEAR $SALARY;
   datalines;
A123   4Mar1989    8,60000
A037  23Jun1957   21,45000
M015  19Sep1977   17,50000
;
run;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data i;
  input DEPT $1. @1 ID $ BIRTHDAY :date9. +(-5) YEAR :8. SALARY comma10.0;
  datalines;
A123   4Mar1989    8,60000
A037  23Jun1957   21,45000
M015  19Sep1977   17,50000
;
run;
```

This uses formatted input with pointer controls to double back over parts that need to be read twice. Please refer to the documentation for the input statement for further details.

You could also use `substr` to extract `DEPT` from `ID`, or the `year` function to extract that from `BIRTHDAY`.

Comment: Thx, this works for the first set, however when combining the sets the * also appears. Im having trouble removing them, when combining the sets.

Comment: Are you importing the other records from a separate file or from within the same file? What have you tried so far for those records?

Comment: From within the same file, as it stands in the offsite data, mentioned in the original question. I´tried saving them as two seperate datasets and then merging them, which dosent solve the issue.